# Adding RadioButtons depending on array programatically

Tags: android

I want to add radio buttons to a question as the options for answering, but these have to be added on the code because the amount of options depends on each item. These as the multiple choice answer options aren't always limited to one option selected, that can change also sometimes 2 or more options are required to be selected.

I'm doing this in a recyclerView, is there a way to add them without being in a radio group in order to be able to select more than one button when required?

Comment: Have you considered using checkboxes instead? Usually, these are preferred if multiple choice is possible.

Comment: @Marek I'm down for whatever is best I just don't know how to approach it

Comment: A suggestion; If you have question and many answers, using [chip](https://material.io/components/chips) is better for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using checkboxes, I'd probably go for that approach.

You could introduce an `Answer` model class and add a `Checkbox` with an `OnCheckedChangeListener` to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s `ViewHolder`:

```java
public class Answer {
    private String text;
    private boolean isChecked;

    // Constructor, Getters, Setters
}
```

```java
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int MAX_ANSWERS = 2;

    private List<Answer> mData;
    private Context context;

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Answer> data, Context context) {
        this.mData = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // ...

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkAnswer;
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkAnswer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_answer);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Answer answer = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(answer.getText());
        holder.checkAnswer.setOnCheckedChangeListener((v, isChecked) -> {
            answer.setChecked(isChecked);
            // Notify adapter so that onBindViewHolder is called 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        // Check whether maximum number of answers is reached
        if (mData.stream().filter(Answer::isChecked).count() >= MAX_ANSWERS) {
            holder.checkAnswer.setEnabled(holder.checkAnswer.isChecked());
        } else {
            holder.checkAnswer.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

After creating a list of answers, it can be passed to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. 
(For further information on how to update the data, please refer to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#Adapter))

```java
List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
answers.add(new Answer("Answer 1"));
answers.add(new Answer("Answer 2"));

recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(answers, this));

//...
```

Whenever an answer is submitted, you can filter the list for checked answers:

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    List<Answer> selected = answers.stream().filter(Answer::isChecked).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Could I limit the amount of checkboxes that are selected?

Comment: You could check whether a maximum number of answers is reached and depending on that enable or disable checkboxes. I updated the answer correspondingly (`onBindViewHolder`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily with android's built-in dialogs. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#AddingAList) is Android's official documentations.

Comment: This is for a survey not for a dialog box, if the user has to open a dialog box for each multiple choice question that's not user friendly at all. What if the survey has 20 multiple choice questions?